# Homeomorphic implies quasi-isomorphic

Tags: metric-spaces, geometric-topology, geometric-group-theory

[image]

I'm wondering if this is the way to go? Or should I continue in a different direction?

Comment: This is not true. $(0,1)$ and $\Bbb R$ are not quasi-isometric.

Comment: @MikeMiller are you sure?  I couldn't find any proof that (0,1) and R are not quasi-isometric. Can you please explain why it is?

Comment: The metric on $Y$ is bounded, but not the metric on $X$, so the second inequality is impossible.

Comment: OK, Thanks, just for clarification in your last comment X is (0,1) and Y is R